# Can I use a metal radio housing as an antenna?

Tags: antenna

I'm in the very early design stages of building an FM/Bluetooth receiver into a Drive-In Theater Speaker casing. Since the case is made of cast aluminum, is there any way I can make use of the case/shell to act as the radio antenna?

Comment: If you can, it'd be a horrible one. I wouldn't expect it to get good reception.

Answer (score 1):

The case will act as a shield, greatly impairing the efficiency of any internal antenna.

If you're willing to drill a hole in the case, a short wire protruding through it will act as a pretty good antenna.

If the speaker grille is made of simple horizontal bars, you might be able to break one off and put your Bluetooth antenna in the empty space to get a little more efficiency.

It is possible to use the metal of the case, causing radio frequency currents to flow on it, with a "slot" antenna design. But this is a very sophisticated design undertaking, not really practical for your use case.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case (no pun intended), so thank you for the confirmation... I may go with a retractable antenna, if I can find one thats about 4", and foldable...

Comment: If you search for "external bluetooth antenna" you'll find lots of options. Find one that mounts with a connector, and has a short pigtail of coax to connect to your BT module.